# how to store whole resume inside mysql database in servlet/jsp?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

**Resume uploading/downloading in java**

i want to store my resumes inside mysql database and then download in my system. resume size is upto 5 mb. how to do it??

currently i i saved path in database and resume in a folder.

Comment: What format are your resumes? You can always store them as blobs.

Comment: it is in .doc,.docx,.pdf,.txt

Comment: check this ..it may help u a bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430008/inserting-blob-data-in-java-using-preparedstatement

Comment: Why change your current approach of storing files in your filesystem (a highly optimised file storage database) and relational data in your RDBMS (a highly optimised relational database)?

Comment: Code for inserting image and word file is same???

Comment: hello eggyal , i want to change my approach because it work fine in local but file  name get changed when uploaded on live server

Comment: Blobs store binary data: images, word files, videos... you name it, you can pretty much store any file or anything binary in blobs.

Answer (score 0):

Refer `ServletFileUpload()` provided by the servlet Technology, the below is a piece of code demonstrating the reading of file submited by the client.

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  ServletException, IOException {
 try {
    List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new  DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
     for (FileItem item : items) {
        if (item.isFormField()) {
            // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
            String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
            String fieldvalue = item.getString();
            // ... (do your job here)
        } else {
            // Process form file field (input type="file").
            String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
            String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
            InputStream filecontent = item.getInputStream();
            // store your file in mysql db
         }
     }
  } catch (FileUploadException e) {
     throw new ServletException("Cannot read the file", e);
  }

   // ...
  }
```

servlet is a forefather of jsp, therefore you can use the same method in jsp also.