# Insert BLOB from a file into a sql script to embed H2 database

Tags: sql, database, integration-testing, h2

I'm creating a SQL script to create a new schema and insert some values to an embed H2 database for use with integration tests in a Spring Boot application. One of the values I need to insert is a BLOB field on the sql table.

I've succesfully used the `FILE_READ` function as described [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#file_read).

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(ID, NAME, LOGO) 
VALUES('1', 'test1', FILE_READ('C:/myproject/logo.png'));
```

That function works well with full paths but I'm not been able to do that with relative paths. That doesn't work well when the sources are downloaded and compiled (plus testing) in any other machine than mine.

**I need to insert into a sql script a BLOB field from a binary file, loaded from a relative path from the project that owns that script.**

I've searched and found this aproach: [insert a BLOB via a sql script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607326/insert-a-blob-via-a-sql-script)
But `RAWTOHEX` function seems to work with Strings, and my input is a binary file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`FILE_READ`](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#file_read) documentation:

> File names and URLs are supported. To read a stream from the
>   classpath, use the prefix classpath:

Seems that the use of a relative path it's not possible; then a possible solution is to include the file with the desired binary content in the `classpath` and access it using `classpath:` in `FILE_READ`. This way you can deploy it in any other machine without worries about the absolute paths.

**By code using `RunScript`**

So if before perform your test you setup the DB running the script by code using something like:

```
RunScript.execute(conn, new FileReader("yourScript.sql"));
```

Then add the `logo.png` as a resource of your project this way you can refer it inside the script using `classpath:` notation: `FILE_READ('classpath:/your/package/resource/logo.png')`.

**Using `RunScript` from command line tool**

If you use the command line tool, you can create a *.jar* to package your resources, e.g `resource.jar` and add it to `classpath` in your cmd:

`java -cp h2*.jar;resource.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:~/test -script yourScript.sql`

Then as the previous case in your script you can refer your binary file using `FILE_READ('classpath:/your/package/resource/logo.png')`

Hope it helps,

Comment: It works! I was missing 'classpath:' prefix! Thanks!

Comment: can we avoid runscript?